# Synchronizing state between tabs in UITabBarController

Tags: ios, architecture, uitabbarcontroller, observer-pattern, notificationcenter

An app has a set of screens (tabs) configured with the `UITabBarController`.
Each tab has own `UINavigationController` instance.
Each `UINavigationBar` has a button with dropdown. Selecting a row in a dropdown should trigger a `contentReload` event in some of the `UIViewController`s and update the `UINavigationBar`s.

What is the best way to synchronize multiple tabs of the app?
I have multiple options in mind:

1. An Observer pattern: create a `State` class to store the shared
   state (what item is currently selected) and propagate it to all of
   the observers
2. Use `NotificationCenter` and subscribe all the relevant objects to the changes.
3. Share an instance of `State` between all of the controllers, monitor changes using `KVO`.

Should there be any preference to one method over another? Or is there any standard pattern of handling such app state transitions?

Example of the UI, the dropdown is accessible on every controller: 
[image]

Comment: Combination of MVVM and [**RXSwift**](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift) would be a good solution.

Comment: @Nitish thanks. MVVM + RxSwift falls into 1st/3rd category to me.